# HTML/CSS use DOS Codepage 437 font / missing glyphs

Tags: html, css, ascii, font-face, codepages

I want to use the classic DOS Codepage437 fonts on a HTML web page. I've included a *.ttf file with CSS and normal letters do work. But there a some missing glyphs, that are interpreted as control characters (for example the nice dos style smileys :D or chinese yen sign). How can I force the browser to display e.g. glyph 0x0E of the ttf-file?

See [Link to  example html file](http://bananapi.patrickkresmer.de/test.html) (ttf file can be found in source code)

This is how it should look like:

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

tl;dr: You can't use the DOS 437 character set on a web page.

---

One problem is that browsers interpret numeric character references as Unicode codepoints. In your example page, `&#200;` always means U+00C8 LATIN CAPITAL LETTER E WITH GRAVE.
Now you're using a font where U+00C8 happens to look like `╚` instead of `È`, but that doesn't matter.
Or rather, it *does* matter, because it only contributes to the confusion. You say, "normal letters do work", but they don't "work"; they are simply displayed, but the result is not what you expect.
As a test, try to display

```
&#212;&#213;&#214;&#215;&#216;&#217;&#218;
```

using your font. Then double click on the first character, to select the whole word. You will see that only the first three characters get selected, because `&#212;&#213;&#214;` is a word. `&#215;` is not a letter, and thus not part of a word, no matter the font!

The same is true for numerical references below 32, like `&#25;` where the font may contain `↓` at that position, but the browser knows that this is Unicode U+0019 END OF MEDIUM, a non-printing character. So it won't be printed.

Another, unrelated, problem with your webpage is that you specify `UTF-8` for the charset, rather than `IBM437`.
Browsers are not obliged to honour uncommon codepages though, so it won't magically start working if you change it. In addition, numerical references like `&#200;` still mean *Unicode* codepoint 200 rather than the 200th glyph in your font.
So in this case, it won't really make much of a difference what charset you specify.

---

The solution, then, is to create a Unicode compatible font, that has the glyphs mapped to the correct codepoints (`╚` is at codepoint U+255A, and so on) and use them by referring to said codepoints in the HTML (`&#x255A;` or `&#9562;`). Or of course, use UTF-8 and simply type `╚` into your editor.